# Using Sandcastle with Unity & VS 2015 Tools

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, unity-game-engine, sandcastle

I'm trying to create API docs from a Unity project with Sandcastle Help File Builder but I'm getting the following error:

```
SHFB: Error BE0040: Project assembly does not exist: C:\Users\user\Unity\Projects\proj\Temp\UnityVS_bin\Debug\Assembly-CSharp.dll
   at SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.BuildProcess.ValidateDocumentationSources()
   at SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.BuildProcess.Build()
```

So I copied the missing Assembly-CSharp.dll from Library/ScriptAssemblies into the above temp path. Now i'm getting the following error:

```
SHFB: Error BE0041: Project XML comments file does not exist: C:\Users\user\Unity\Projects\proj\Temp\UnityVS_bin\Debug\Assembly-CSharp.XML
   at SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.BuildProcess.ValidateDocumentationSources()
   at SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.BuildProcess.Build()
```

Can anyone help to get this working?